# Read User Input from keyboard as string till user inputs empty line

Tags: java

Read User Input from keyboard as string till user inputs empty line and write all lines to a file? this is my ques, should i want to convert the user input into multiple lines in strings and store it in files????"

```
    String inputText="";

    while (inputText.equals("")) {

            System.out.println("enter");

            inputText = reader.nextLine();

            writer.write(inputText);

            writer.write("\n");
    }
```

Comment: How user will add empty line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
String inputText="";
    while (true) {
            System.out.println("enter");
            inputText = reader.nextLine();
            if(inputText.equals(""))
              break;
            else
              writer.write(inputText);
            writer.write("\n");
    }
```